# Blogger API Search using Labels

Tags: blogger

I have been searching my blog thru Perl with

```
 my $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/"
     . BLOG_ID . "/posts/search?q=" . $searchTerm
    . "&key=" . API_KEY . "&maxResults=9999";
 my $json_data = geturl($url);
```

Normally, I get back the group of posts I want, with one or two extra that I can parse out.

But now, my search returns 10 posts, none of which I want, as my search term seems to be too generic.

When I use the web-interface, I can search/filter by label, which is what I would like to do. But adding "&labels=$searchTerm" to my $url, doesn't make a differs.

Is there some way I can filter the search results either by label or title that $url returns?

I seem to be limited to 10 posts, even with "maxResults".

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the publicly available feeds for filtering posts by labels -

```
https://blog.name/feeds/posts/default/-/LabelToFilterBy?max-results=20&alt=json
```

A live example -

https://developers.googleblog.com/feeds/posts/default/-/android?max-results=50&alt=json